# Using Ruby OAuth to connect to Yahoo Contacts API

Tags: rest, oauth, yahoo

I've been trying to work with the Yahoo Contacts API using the latest 
version of Ruby OAuth, but I'm not sure if I'm getting hung up with 
the last stage of the authorization process, or something in the API. 
I hope you can help me figure that out.

Using the current version of OAuth, I'm able to apparently receive a 
working access key. I have a controller which requests the 
request_token like so:

```
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(api_key, shared_secret, 
{ 
:site => 'https://api.login.yahoo.com', 
:request_token_path => '/oauth/v2/get_request_token', 
:access_token_path => '/oauth/v2/get_token', 
:authorize_path => '/oauth/v2/request_auth',
:signature_method => 'HMAC-SHA1', 
:oauth_version => '1.0' 
}) 

@request_token = @consumer.get_request_token( 
{:oauth_callback => 'http://contactmonkey.com/cards/yahoo_auth?redir...@card.short_link} 
)
```

I get an apparently good request token from this, and proceed after 
authorization in the new controller method:

```
@access_token = 
@request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier=>params[:oauth_verifier])
```

I get an apparently good access token from this as well. It's only 
when I start using the API that things get pear-shaped.

```
# make initial contact so we get a contact ID 
yahoo_guid = @access_token.params[:xoauth_yahoo_guid] 
@response = @access_token.request(:post, 'http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/' + yahoo_guid + '/contacts')
```

When I inspect the response body, I get this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><error xmlns=\"http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng\" xmlns:yahoo=\"http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng\" yahoo:uri=\"http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/errors/415\" yahoo:lang=\"en-US\"><description>Requested representation not available for the resource</description><detail>Invalid media type</detail></error>
```

I've seen in many places that there's some incompatibility between the 
Yahoo OAuth implementation and the Ruby OAuth gem. But I'm not sure if 
that information is out of date (I'm using the current 0.4.4).

Thanks for any help you can offer! 
Aaron.

**Update:** The solution is to format the header correctly:

```
@response =  @access_token.request(:post, 'http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/' + yahoo_guid + '/contacts', entry, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/xml' } )
```

Note the "content-type" header. I'd tried "text/xml", but that doesn't work. This does. Thanks to Dan K. for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an HTTP 415 back, which means the server is unable to respond to your request in your requested format.  The Yahoo APIs appear to support two ways of specifying which formats you want.  From [the docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/web-services-http-responses.html), they are:

1.) Set the "Accept" HTTP Header with your requested content-type (either XML or JSON).

2.) Append ?format=xml or ?format=json to your query string.

Comment: Okay, that was a good lead! I specified an XML request, and tried again. I'm getting a different error now, so this is progress... :-) The Error is <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo='http://yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng'\n  xml:lang='en-US'>\n  <yahoo:description>application/x-www-form-urlencoded not supported with OAuth</yahoo:description>\n</yahoo:error>\n<!-- ws109.socdir.ac4.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Fri Jan 14 06:05:40 PST 2011 -->\n

Comment: By the way, this is how I sent the request using OAuth: @response =  @access_token.request(:post, 'http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/' + yahoo_guid + '/contacts', { 'Content-Type' => 'application/atom+xml' } )

Comment: It sounds like you're setting your "Content-Type" request header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  So I guess your attempt to set it to "application/atom+xml" isn't working.  Can you refer to your docs to see how to set the Content-Type?

Comment: Another thing you can do is use an intercepting proxy or a packet sniffer like wireshark to take a look at the actual HTTP request you're sending.  That will make it really clear what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that helped as well. I used Wireshark to detect my outgoing packets, and confirmed that I am sending as type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". But you can see above I'm trying to set the header to send "application/atom+xml" (I've also tried "text/xml" to the same effect). I guess my next step is to attempt to sort out how to really change the header, but I'm open to suggestions... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also had hard time with yahoo oauth, and yahoo api request for "HAMC-SHA1". After gone throught all the hard things, I created a long document here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SdGSfakQM3ZuiqJK7keXhOfh6310-z_h0THl1_Jswxk/pub

Because it too long that I cannot write everything here. I hope that it might help some one else.